# To add page views of certain documents in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, view, numbers, show

I am not able to add a feature to show the user how many users have seen the certain page in SharePoint. Please help with it.
To create a new feature that will be able to give the user insight about the page views of certain page on the interface of SharePoint.
Give the solution about it.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can active the **SharePoint Viewers** Site Features to display the viewers of the files and pages.

[image]

[image]